# Given a truth table for a boolean function, write down the formula for f using $\cap, \cup, \neg$

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra

I was given the following task

> Truth table of boolean function $f(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n)$ with $n$
> variables is defined with numbers $a_{k1,...kp} \in (0,1)$, which are
> equal to the value of the function on list $(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n)$, which
> consists of zeroes and ones, where ones are on the places $k_1, k_p$,
> where $k_1 \le 1 < ...<k_P\le n$ . Using table, write down the formula
> for $f$ using operations $\cap, \cup, \neg$

For those of you, who know Russian this is the translation of the problem

> Таблица истинности булевой функции $f(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n)$ от $n$ переменных, описывается числами $a_{k1,...kp} \in (0,1)$, равными значению функции на наборе $(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n)$, из нулей и единиц, в котором единицы стоят на местах $k_1, k_p$,
> где$k_1 \le 1 < ...<k_P\le n$. Зная эту таблицу выпишите формулу для $f$ с использованием $\cap, \cup, \neg$

1. How do we calculate the value of such a function?

2. I do not understand the task. Could you please describe it more clear?

Comment: It seems to be a generalization of it
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: Думаю, что авторы хотели написать $a_{k_1,\ldots,k_p}in\{0,1\}$. $(0,1)$-это часто означивает закрытый интерваль $\langle 0,1\rangle$.